# How to install MIT Scheme on Mac?

Tags: macos, scheme, mit-scheme

I want to install [MIT Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) on my Mac, I have downloaded the *MacOS X binary(x86-64)*.

However, I could not make it work using Mac Terminal.

I have tried to follow these articles:

[Installing MIT/GNU Scheme on Mac OS X Leopard](http://renevanbelzen.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/installing-mitgnu-scheme-on-mac-os-x-leopard/)

<s>[Installing MIT Scheme on Mac OS X](https://wiki.umn.edu/CSCI1901/InstallingMITScheme)</s>

but it seems out of date and does not work.

So, I'm looking for a simple method which allows me to write Scheme code using Mac Terminal.

I have struggled for hours to try to install it.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What does it do, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: @Cody the 1st link assume what you downloaded is a tar file, but what i download is a dmz file , and for the 2nd link after i type the command sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme /usr/bin/scheme , followed by type "scheme" it does not work according to the post.

Comment: again, you have to be more specific than "does not work". what is the error message that you get when you try to run the command?

Comment: How is this "not related to programming"? Stackoverflow really blows these days

Comment: @Cody there is no error message.i just follow the instruction from 2nd article and it does not work without error message

Comment: [This](https://wiki.umn.edu/CSCI1901/InstallingMITScheme) is the cleanest instruction I've found so far. No need to install anything else. Although it says Mountain Lion, it works for me (Lion 10.7.5). In fact it would work for any mac on Intel processor.

Comment: @Timeless: The second article you referenced ("Installing MIT Scheme on Mac OS X") is now a dead link, i.e., "UMWiki Retired June 30, 2016." So, it's even more out of date. :-)

Answer (score 85):

**UPDATED FOR EL CAPITAN**:

The best way that I've found was from [here](https://jacksonisaac.wordpress.com/2014/03/25/installing-scheme-on-mac-os-x/):

1. Download either the [32-bit](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/stable.pkg/9.2/mit-scheme-9.2-i386.dmg) or [64-bit](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/stable.pkg/9.2/mit-scheme-9.2-x86-64.dmg) dmg file for Scheme.
2. Double click the .dmg file, and you'll get this window, in which you should drag the "MIT/GNU Scheme" file into the Applications folder.[image]
3. **For the 32-bit version**, run this command:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-i386
   ```

   Then enter your administrator password, and run this command:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-i386/mit-scheme /usr/local/bin/scheme
   ```

   **For the 64-bit version**, first run this command:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64
   ```

   Then enter your administrator password and run this command:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64/mit-scheme /usr/local/bin/scheme
   ```

---

And that's it! Now you should be able to use MIT Scheme in your terminal by typing "scheme" into the command line:

[image]

Comment: I already had it installed but I had no idea I could use it from my own terminal. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: what about `brew install mit-scheme `

Comment: No, *now* you run `M-x run-scheme`! Is there any other way? No.

Comment: Thank you @Snowmanzzz . Or you can use services like repl.it in '19

Answer (score 41):

Homebrew makes it easy for you. On Terminal, type:

<strike>`ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go) ; brew install mit-scheme`</strike>

Done!

**Edit**

The install script has been moved:

```bash
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" ; brew install mit-scheme
```

Comment: Hmm, yes sorry. Homebrew has some prerequisites: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation

Comment: Anyway, running this worked just fine for me and afterwards it launches with 'mit-scheme' :)

Comment: hi,i got this error:Failed executing: etc/make-liarc.sh --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mit-scheme/9.1.1 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/mit-scheme/9.1.1/share/man (mit-scheme.rb:39) any idea...thanks.

Comment: @null The error is due to differences in Xcode versions. If you have the latest Xcode installed, running `brew update` would work IMO. However, if you don't have Xcode, then we both are on the same boat!

Comment: Careful ! The install script has moved from http://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go to http://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install !

Comment: If you already installed homebrew, then just need `brew install mit-scheme`

Comment: ```ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"```

Comment: This answer no longer works.  mit-scheme now needs the hombrew/x11 tap AND a very inconvenient install of xquartz.  At least on 10.10.

Comment: brew cask install xquartz && brew install mit-scheme

Answer (score 41):

<s>For Yosemite 10.10.3:</s>

After installing X11.app and homebrew,

```
$ brew tap homebrew/x11
$ brew install mit-scheme
```

I found it easier when a maintained package manager such as homebrew covers all the dependency and build stuff.

---

Edit: simply

```
$ brew install mit-scheme
```

would do. X11 is now optional instead of dependence. There is still an `--with-x11` option which requires whole Xcode.

Answer (score 23):

You can install scheme using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) using the following command

```
brew install mit-scheme
```

Comment: Note that `mit-scheme` requires XQuartz (X11.app), and that XQuartz is no longer distributed with OSX past Mountain Lion. To install `mit-scheme` through homebrew, you will need to install XQuartz first, else an error will stop the install.

You can download and install XQuartz from their [site](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) yourself, or check out the [cask extension for homebrew](http://caskroom.io/), through which you can install XQuartz.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the latest version of Mac system, **El Capitan 10.11.2**, You might need to do something different than above.

The first command will be same.
**For the 64-bit version**, first run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MIT\:GNU\ Scheme.app/Contents/Resources /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64
```

Then enter your administrator password and run this command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64/mit-scheme /usr/local/bin/scheme`

Note: The difference is you need to put **local** between /usr/ and /bin/

Type scheme in the terminal to see if it works. If you get the following screenshot, that means you succeed it.

[Success Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmgH1.png)

You definitely need to put **local** there. 
The reason is this, Apple improved OS security in OSX 10.10 (rootless), and changes to the general system-wide binaries (such as /usr/bin) is not permitted.

Answer (score 6):

If you are having trouble with the accepted answer from @virgil-ming, try this:

```
$ brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
$ brew install mit-scheme
```

Same idea, of course, but this got me up and running when `brew tap homebrew/x11` responded with multiple conflicts.

As always, remember to `brew update` then try again when you are having problems, a la [Homebrew's troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#check-for-common-issues).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using docker, and I recommend you do:

`docker run -it inikolaev/alpine-scheme`

will drop you right into a scheme REPL.

Comment: It is what I want.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE FOR MAC OS HIGH SIERRA:**

Worked for me just by executing (if you are using Homebrew):

`brew install mit-scheme`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MacPorts, the command is similar to what others have posted for homebrew -

```
sudo port install mit-scheme
```

That set me up pretty well on OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I came across a problem that the **10.x** versions of the *MIT/GNU Scheme* do not support *Mac OS X* **10.11** *El Capitan*. In fact, it requires *Mac OS X* **10.13 or higher**.

The topmost version supporting older *Mac OS X* versions is *MIT/GNU Scheme* **9.2**.