# How can I start up scheme in mac os(10.11.3)?

Tags: macos, scheme

I do exactly as @Alex K say in [How to install MIT Scheme on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322434/how-to-install-mit-scheme-on-mac)

But I get this:

> scheme: can't find a readable default for option --band.
>       searched for file all.com in these directories:
>       /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-i386

Anyone can solve this problem?

when i solve this problem,another happen:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64/
-rw-r--r--@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin    13M  5 17  2014 all.com
-rw-r--r--@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin   420K 12 23  2009 appIcon.icns
drwxr-xr-x@  12 zhangxiaolin  admin   408B  5 17  2014 compiler
drwxr-xr-x@  21 zhangxiaolin  admin   714B  5 17  2014 cref
drwxr-xr-x@ 191 zhangxiaolin  admin   6.3K  5 17  2014 edwin
drwxr-xr-x@  16 zhangxiaolin  admin   544B  5 17  2014 ffi
drwxr-xr-x@  30 zhangxiaolin  admin   1.0K  5 17  2014 imail
drwxr-xr-x@   5 zhangxiaolin  admin   170B  5 17  2014 lib
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin   530K  5 17  2014 mit-scheme
-rw-r--r--@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin   3.7K  5 17  2014 mit-scheme.h
-rw-r--r--@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin   3.9K  5 17  2014 optiondb.scm
drwxr-xr-x@ 206 zhangxiaolin  admin   6.8K  5 17  2014 runtime
drwxr-xr-x@  43 zhangxiaolin  admin   1.4K  5 17  2014 sf
-rw-r--r--@   1 zhangxiaolin  admin   936B  5 17  2014 shim-config.scm
drwxr-xr-x@  18 zhangxiaolin  admin   612B  5 17  2014 sos
drwxr-xr-x@  14 zhangxiaolin  admin   476B  5 17  2014 ssp
drwxr-xr-x@  12 zhangxiaolin  admin   408B  5 17  2014 star-parser
drwxr-xr-x@  28 zhangxiaolin  admin   952B  5 17  2014 xml

$./mit-scheme
unable to mmap executable heap -- native code will probably failRequested allocation is too large.
Try again with a smaller argument to '--heap'.
```

`$ scheme`  is alias of `$ ./mit-scheme` how could they do different thing?

Comment: i give up, use brew  !!!

Comment: Some applications behave differently depending on which name you invoke them with - for instance, `bash` behaves differently if you invoke it as `sh` (which is a symlink to `bash` on your Mac).